# the persistent menu of facebook messenger bot is not being update with the last changes

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot, botkit

I am using botkit to build my bot. The first time I validated my webhook the persistent menu that was there was the one which came as example :

```
controller.api.thread_settings.menu([
        {
            "type":"postback",
            "title":"Hello",
            "payload":"hello"
        },
        {
            "type":"postback",
            "title":"Help",
            "payload":"help"
        },
        {
          "type":"web_url",
          "title":"Botkit Docs",
          "url":"https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/blob/master/readme-facebook.md"
        },
    ]);
```

I changed the persistent menu to :

```
controller.api.thread_settings.menu([
        {
            "type":"postback",
            "title":"Account",
            "payload":"account"
        },
        {
            "type":"postback",
            "title":"News",
            "payload":"news"
        },
        {
            "type": "postback",
            "title": "Contact",
            "payload": "contact"
        },
    ]);
```

But it has been 3 days without being change to what I set. I would like to understand what is wrong and when exactly does facebook messenger update the menu?
I even tried to use curl to delete and add the persistent menu but nothing is working.

Comment: Something wrongs with Facebook instead. I configured my menus via curl, but top-level 'postback' menus didn't work, only nested ones work. you can refer to here: https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/issues/764

Comment: curl is not working at all for me, I don't know what it is wrong even when whitelisting domains curl is not work, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552879/domains-are-not-being-added-whitelist-domains-facebook-messenger-extension is this one of the problem that curl refuses to solve.

Answer (score 2):

You must delete the conversation thread and begin it again to see the changes take effect.

Also, FB changed the payload structure for this, you need to set the locale, and put the menu items in a `call_to_actions` array.

```
 controller.api.thread_settings.menu([
       { "locale": "default",
         "compose_input_disabled": false,
         "call_to_actions": [
           {
          "title":"My Account",
          "type":"nested",
          "call_to_actions":[
            {
              "title":"Pay Bill",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"PAYBILL_PAYLOAD"
            },
            {
              "title":"History",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"HISTORY_PAYLOAD"
            },
            {
              "title":"Contact Info",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"CONTACT_INFO_PAYLOAD"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
            "type":"postback",
            "title":"Help",
            "payload":"help"
        },
        {
          "type":"web_url",
          "title":"Botkit Docs",
          "url":"https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/blob/master/readme-facebook.md"
        }
      ]
        }

    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need these 2 methods: removePersistentMenu and addPersistentMenu.

https://github.com/matthewericfisher/fb-robot/blob/master/app.js

Be patient, it can take a minute, check your console for the response.

You also need to remove your conversation with the bot in facebook messenger.