# Domains are not being added, Whitelist domains facebook messenger extension

Tags: node.js, facebook-messenger, whitelist, facebook-messenger-bot, botkit

I've been trying to whitelist my domains following the instruction that is given by facebook but nothing is working.

I first tried with curl, the response is `{result:"success"}` but when I try to list the domains that are whitelisted I am getting `{data:[]}`

Then I tried using node request module as follow:

```
request.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=sfdlksdfu79r9429049824982342348sjdfsf", {
                "setting_type": "domain_whitelisting",
                "whitelisted_domains": ["https://mydomainw.com", "https://mydomainw.com/profile", "https://sfujyx.com/ofr", "mydomain1.com", "mydomain.com"],
                "domain_action_type": "add"}, function (err, res, body) {
                console.log("Whitelisting domain");
                if (!err) {
                    console.log(body);
                    console.log("Showing the list of whitelisted:");
                    request.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?fields=whitelisted_domains&access_token=sfdlksdfu79r9429049824982342348sjdfsf", function (err, res, body) {
                        if (!err) {
                            console.log(body);
                        } else {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
```

Still it bring the same result as curl :

[image: Screen shot of the result of the code]

And when I use Facebook Graph Api Explorer tool, here is the error I am getting:

[image: Graph Api tool, to whitelist domain]

I am really stuck, I don't know what should I do or how people exactly whitelist domain for messenger extension.

What I am doing wrong? why isn't the domains being added?

My project is on Google App Engine.

Comment: I think you're using wrong api path. It should be "/me/messenger_profile" instead.

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'me' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "BDenwqcm3BD"
  }
} Is the response I get when I put /me/messenger_profile @MichealVu

Comment: you got above message because you're using wrong access_token. You should try to get Page Access Token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is I was using the App Access Token instead of the Page Access Token, I didn't know the difference.

Answer (score 2):

your domain: "https://mydomainw..com" is an invalid domain.

The request should return:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) whitelisted_domains[0] should represent a valid URL",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "Aq3AVaNVJU9"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Micheal Vu , https://mydomainw..com is not correct I meant https://mydomainw.com but anyway all these domains are not mine they are there for illustration of what I was doing. I didn't want to give out the true domain that I want to whitelist. I've also added more information because since last time I keep trying different methods(graph api tool) but nothing is working yet. Do you need my true domain to try?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I didn't use "setting_type" before. This is how I register domains:

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile',
  qs: { access_token: 'my_page_token' },
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
  body: 
   { whitelisted_domains: 
      [ 
        'https://mydomainw.com',
        'https://ijuugwivbc.localtunnel.me' ] },
  json: true };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: I'm doing same thing but i have an array of strings that has the all domains to be whitelisted and  want to assign an array to whitelisted_domains rather than just feeding it strings, how can i do  that?